# How to parse rsync stats data?

Tags: bash, rsync, automator

As result of `rsync` run with `-stats` option, I get something like below at the end of log:

```
Number of files: 619
Number of files transferred: 0
Total file size: 134.50M bytes
Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 22880
File list generation time: 0.250 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 22.90K
Total bytes received: 20
```

I would like to show `Number of files transferred` and `Total transferred file size` in the automator's notification. So I should extract this data somehow and pass further. How could I do it? Will `grep` help here?

Answer (score 3):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk '/Number of files|Number of files/{print $NF}' file
619
0
```

If you want full lines then:

```
awk '/Number of files|Number of files/' file
Number of files: 619
Number of files transferred: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep` for full lines:

```
grep -e "Number of files transferred" -e "Total transferred file size"
```

Using `grep` for only the values:

```
grep -Po '(?<=Number of files transferred: |Total transferred file size: ).*'
```

More flexible using `perl`:

```
perl -wne '/(.*): (.*)/ and $h{$1}=$2}{print "Number: $h{\"Number of files transferred\"}  Size: $h{\"Total transferred file size\"}\n"'
```

Comment: Note as of rsync version 3.1.0, "Number of files transferred" is now "Number of regular files transferred". I can't see any other (more robust) way of extracting this information from rsync output (than what is suggested in the answers here), so any script which attempts to extract this information should be capable of flagging up a problem if it can't find the information (because of any other future changes in the text of the rsync output).